# SQL query value depending on other linked table multiple values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

First of all, sorry if the title is not quite descriptive, but I didn't know how to describe what I want to achieve. My database system is an SQL Server 2008 R2. The issue is the following:

I have two tables, A and B, with a 1..* relationship, linked by table A's Id. I want to query table A with a single value of table B depending on this rule:

1. If no matching records in table B then write "red"
2. If all the records in table B are "NONE" then write "red"
3. If all the records in table B are "ALL" then write "green"
4. If we have a mixture of "NONE" and "ALL", then write "yellow"
5. If any of the matching rows in table B is "PARTIAL" then write "yellow"

"ALL","PARTIAL","NONE" are the only available values in table B, in case of any.

Can anyone help me to get that? Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add example data and expected results.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that table A has a column called `id`, and table B has a column called `a_id` and `value`, you can use a combination of an `outer join` and some `group`ing to feed a `case` statement some aggregate values.

```
select
    a.id,
    case
        when (max(b.a_id) is null) then "red" -- No match found
        when (min(b.value) = "NONE" and max(b.value) = "NONE") then "red" -- All B values are "NONE"
        when (min(b.value) = "ALL" and max(b.value) = "ALL") then "green" -- All B values are "ALL"
        when (max(case when (b.value = "PARTIAL") then 1 else 0 end) = 1) then "yellow" -- At least one B value contains "PARTIAL"
        when (max(case when (b.value = "NONE") then 1 else 0 end) = 1 and max(case when (b.value = "ALL") then 1 else 0 end) = 1) then "yellow" -- A mix of "NONE" and "ALL"
        else "Undefined"
    end
from
    table_a a
    left outer join table_b b
        on (a.id=b.a_id)
group by
    a.id
```

Most of the logic here is in the `case` statement. The use of `min()` and `max()` to compare the values in table B is pretty straight forward, and should be self explanatory - if not, simply add `min(b.value)` and `max(b.value)` to your select statement to see what values are outputted, to help visualize it.  The trickier part to understand is the rule for "partial". That portion of the case statement evaluated the value of every row from table B, and if it is "partial", then it returns the value "1" for that row. After the query has evaluated all the B rows for the group, it select the `max()` value to see if a "1" was ever returned.

Comment: WIll this hit the "PARTIAL" condition? I think the question needs more clarification, because `AT LEAST ONE PARTIAL` is just about the same as `A MIX OF VALUES`. Maybe move that `PARTIAL` check above the `MIX` check, so that it breaks out of the CASE if it finds `PARTIAL`. Otherwise, if all B records were `ALL` ('min(b.value)`)  and `PARTIAL` ('max(b.value)`), then it would hit `MIX` without having any `NONE` values.

Comment: This works too. The only thing I see is I'm not sure you can use `b.a_id` since it's a non-aggregated column. SQL defines transitive dependency for these cases, but I'm not sure it's implemented by SQL Server. +1 anyway.

Comment: Also, if `b.value` can hold more values than `ALL`, `NONE` or `PARTIAL`, I think that would break the `min()/max()` logic. Still, I do think this answer is on the right track. I think we need more definition of the original problem.

Comment: the possible values are "ALL","NONE","PARTIAL" or NULL (no coindicences)

Comment: @OscarMateu Can you please include that in the original question?

Comment: @Shawn good observation regarding the "PARTIAL". The `min() <> max()` comparison was laziness on my part. I've updated the answer to specifically check for a value of "NONE" and "ALL".

Comment: @TheImpaler Can you explain a little bit more about your concern with `b.a_id`? I don't think I understand what problem could arise. This query is only using the `b.a_id` column for the join...It doesn't get used in any place that an aggregated value would be required (in the `select`, or in a `having` clause).

Comment: @RToyo According to the SQL specification, when a `SELECT` has a `GROUP BY` clause, the columns that can be used in the `SELECT` are: a) The columns named in the `GROUP BY` clause "as is", in your case `a.id`; b) Aggregated expressions, such `SUM()`, `MAX()`, etc.; c) Functionally dependent columns from the ones present in the `GROUP BY` clause. This answer includes the column `b.a_id`, and I'm not sure if it falls on any of those categories I mention.

Comment: @TheImpaler Ah I see what you mean now. That's a good point, but checking for a null value from an outer joined table seems to be the exception to the rule (I can't explain why). A quick test shows that the query in this answer works fine, but if it didn't, it could be solved by checking if `max(b.a_id) is null`. For completeness, I'll update the answer to use that method.

Answer (score 2):

You can aggregate and then use the `CASE` clause to triage the cases, as in:

```
select
  a.*,
  case when x.id is null then 'red' -- rule #1
       when x.partial > 0 then 'yellow' -- rule #5
       when x.none > 0 and x.all = 0 then 'red' -- rule #2
       when x.none = 0 and x.all > 0 then 'green' -- rule #3
       when x.none > 0 and x.all > 0 then 'yellow' -- rule #4
       else 'undefined case' -- safety net, for future changes
  end as color
from a
left join (
  select
    a.id,
    sum(case when b.state = 'NONE' then 1 end) as none,
    sum(case when b.state = 'ALL' then 1 end) as all,
    sum(case when b.state = 'PARTIAL' then 1 end) as partial
  from a
  join b on b.a_id = a.id
  group by a.id
) x on a.id = x.id
```

Comment: I changed that:

 sum(case when b.state = 'NONE' then 1 else 0 end) as none,
 sum(case when b.state = 'ALL' then 1 else 0 end) as all,
 sum(case when b.state = 'PARTIAL' then 1 else 0 end) as partial

and it worked too